# Order Facet Bar Plot Labels ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to order the Beer brands in my plot according to a different value than is being plotted on the graph. Here is what I have so far:

```
ggplot(rn, aes(Beer, Move)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill = Beer)) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(ifelse(Move >= 0, "+", "-"), round(Move, 0)), hjust = ifelse(Move >= 0, -0.1, 1.1)), size = 3) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90,  hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5)) +
  coord_flip() +
  facet_grid( ~ Week)
```

[image]

I would like to order the labels on the y axes in the plot below by descending value of the total `Vol` across both `Week` types.

```
rn <- structure(list(Beer = c("TOTAL\nMANUFACTURER", "TOTAL\nMANUFACTURER", 
"BUD ICE", "BUD ICE", "BUD LIGHT", "BUD LIGHT", "BUD LIGHT LIME", 
"BUD LIGHT LIME", "BUD LIGHT\nPLATINUM", "BUD LIGHT\nPLATINUM", 
"BUDWEISER", "BUDWEISER", "BUDWEISER\nSELECT", "BUDWEISER\nSELECT", 
"BUSCH", "BUSCH", "BUSCH LIGHT", "BUSCH LIGHT", "BUSCH\nSIGNATURE\nCOPPER LAGER", 
"BUSCH\nSIGNATURE\nCOPPER LAGER", "KING COBRA", "KING COBRA", 
"MICHELOB ULTRA", "MICHELOB ULTRA", "NATTY DADDY", "NATTY DADDY", 
"NATURAL ICE", "NATURAL ICE", "NATURAL LIGHT", "NATURAL LIGHT", 
"ROLLING ROCK", "ROLLING ROCK", "STELLA ARTOIS", "STELLA ARTOIS"
), Move = c(10.9988965633466, 10.1917719480268, 18.7942890269773, 
17.8379704000208, 8.52818879847615, 6.57322359471904, -1.6643480768426, 
-12.1827006261446, -27.2318264955458, -25.2438712289667, 1.9069242423403, 
0.638652351445872, 35.3911234177604, 32.8505336536518, 21.185972764471, 
22.6051124119408, 38.9175541069643, 38.3366719548672, 27.7826940408763, 
12.5811399710158, 7.61387785160614, 5.3730476632517, 2.523089374317, 
6.65243800531876, 15.6173328636012, 9.99422424529812, 15.8994933396845, 
16.417584385266, -3.80149571073229, -8.0531186783228, 5.89476792019757, 
9.26717373953234, 2.99948475741683, -9.23164967143357), Vol = c(1648111.1, 
5206063.1, 97212.8, 299075.2, 488052.9, 1603105.5, 35031.9, 108055.8, 
24700.5, 76511.2, 218627.9, 686473.6, 7531, 24379.5, 168583.9, 
521768.3, 283476.3, 886896.1, 4086.9, 12142.7, 18267.6, 55111.6, 
28543.5, 90719, 24303.8, 62871.5, 58335.5, 176122.4, 176848.2, 
557538.9, 10981.1, 33924.5, 3527.3, 11367.3), Week = c("3 Week Aggregate", 
"12 Week Aggregate", "3 Week Aggregate", "12 Week Aggregate", 
"3 Week Aggregate", "12 Week Aggregate", "3 Week Aggregate", 
"12 Week Aggregate", "3 Week Aggregate", "12 Week Aggregate", 
"3 Week Aggregate", "12 Week Aggregate", "3 Week Aggregate", 
"12 Week Aggregate", "3 Week Aggregate", "12 Week Aggregate", 
"3 Week Aggregate", "12 Week Aggregate", "3 Week Aggregate", 
"12 Week Aggregate", "3 Week Aggregate", "12 Week Aggregate", 
"3 Week Aggregate", "12 Week Aggregate", "3 Week Aggregate", 
"12 Week Aggregate", "3 Week Aggregate", "12 Week Aggregate", 
"3 Week Aggregate", "12 Week Aggregate", "3 Week Aggregate", 
"12 Week Aggregate", "3 Week Aggregate", "12 Week Aggregate")), .Names = c("Beer", 
"Move", "Vol", "Week"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-34L))
```

Comment: do you want the total manufacturer in there too?

Comment: @rawr preferably, yes.

Comment: if you add this, is this what it should look like when you run the same ggplot code? `rn$Beer <- with(rn, factor(Beer, levels = Beer[order(ave(Move, Beer, FUN = sum))]))` you'll get warnings so it is not an ideal answer

Comment: If you change `Move` to `Vol` then yes it is what I'm looking for, but errors abound for that as well... if there is a cleaner way I would appreciate it, but I'll accept that as an answer if you post

Comment: how about just adding `levels = make.unique(...)` does that mess anything up?

Comment: `make.unique` resulted in fatal error: `'names' must be a character vector` while `unique` gave the same warning as your first suggestion and plotted correctly

Comment: hmm, I dont get that error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74260/discussion-between-mkemp6-and-rawr).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rn <- structure(list(Beer = c("TOTAL\nMANUFACTURER", "TOTAL\nMANUFACTURER", 
                              "BUD ICE", "BUD ICE", "BUD LIGHT", "BUD LIGHT", "BUD LIGHT LIME", 
                              "BUD LIGHT LIME", "BUD LIGHT\nPLATINUM", "BUD LIGHT\nPLATINUM", 
                              "BUDWEISER", "BUDWEISER", "BUDWEISER\nSELECT", "BUDWEISER\nSELECT", 
                              "BUSCH", "BUSCH", "BUSCH LIGHT", "BUSCH LIGHT", "BUSCH\nSIGNATURE\nCOPPER LAGER", 
                              "BUSCH\nSIGNATURE\nCOPPER LAGER", "KING COBRA", "KING COBRA", 
                              "MICHELOB ULTRA", "MICHELOB ULTRA", "NATTY DADDY", "NATTY DADDY", 
                              "NATURAL ICE", "NATURAL ICE", "NATURAL LIGHT", "NATURAL LIGHT", 
                              "ROLLING ROCK", "ROLLING ROCK", "STELLA ARTOIS", "STELLA ARTOIS"),
                     Move = c(10.9988965633466, 10.1917719480268, 18.7942890269773, 
            17.8379704000208, 8.52818879847615, 6.57322359471904, -1.6643480768426, 
            -12.1827006261446, -27.2318264955458, -25.2438712289667, 1.9069242423403, 
            0.638652351445872, 35.3911234177604, 32.8505336536518, 21.185972764471, 
            22.6051124119408, 38.9175541069643, 38.3366719548672, 27.7826940408763, 
            12.5811399710158, 7.61387785160614, 5.3730476632517, 2.523089374317, 
            6.65243800531876, 15.6173328636012, 9.99422424529812, 15.8994933396845, 
            16.417584385266, -3.80149571073229, -8.0531186783228, 5.89476792019757, 
            9.26717373953234, 2.99948475741683, -9.23164967143357),
            Vol = c(1648111.1,5206063.1, 97212.8, 299075.2, 488052.9, 1603105.5, 35031.9, 108055.8, 
                                                                            24700.5, 76511.2, 218627.9, 686473.6, 7531, 24379.5, 168583.9, 
                                                                            521768.3, 283476.3, 886896.1, 4086.9, 12142.7, 18267.6, 55111.6, 
                                                                            28543.5, 90719, 24303.8, 62871.5, 58335.5, 176122.4, 176848.2, 
                                                                            557538.9, 10981.1, 33924.5, 3527.3, 11367.3), Week = c("3 Week Aggregate", 
                                                                                                                                   "12 Week Aggregate", "3 Week Aggregate", "12 Week Aggregate", 
                                                                                                                                   "3 Week Aggregate", "12 Week Aggregate", "3 Week Aggregate", 
                                                                                                                                   "12 Week Aggregate", "3 Week Aggregate", "12 Week Aggregate", 
                                                                                                                                   "3 Week Aggregate", "12 Week Aggregate", "3 Week Aggregate", 
                                                                                                                                   "12 Week Aggregate", "3 Week Aggregate", "12 Week Aggregate", 
                                                                                                                                   "3 Week Aggregate", "12 Week Aggregate", "3 Week Aggregate", 
                                                                                                                                   "12 Week Aggregate", "3 Week Aggregate", "12 Week Aggregate", 
                                                                                                                                   "3 Week Aggregate", "12 Week Aggregate", "3 Week Aggregate", 
                                                                                                                                   "12 Week Aggregate", "3 Week Aggregate", "12 Week Aggregate", 
                                                                                                                                   "3 Week Aggregate", "12 Week Aggregate", "3 Week Aggregate", 
                                                                                                                                   "12 Week Aggregate", "3 Week Aggregate", "12 Week Aggregate")), .Names = c("Beer", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                              "Move", "Vol", "Week"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           -34L))
```

The only thing I changed was this line

```
## add this and use make.unique to avoid duplicate factor label warnigs
## everything else stays the same
rn$Beer <- with(rn, factor(Beer, levels = make.unique(Beer[order(ave(Vol, Beer, FUN = sum))])))

library('ggplot2')
ggplot(rn, aes(Beer, Move)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill = Beer)) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(ifelse(Move >= 0, "+", "-"), round(Move, 0)), hjust = ifelse(Move >= 0, -0.1, 1.1)), size = 3) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90,  hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5)) +
  coord_flip() +
  facet_grid( ~ Week)
```

[image]